# Index a pandas dataframe with multiple (row, column) pairs

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and want to update the values based on multiple (row, column) pairs

```
test = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3, 5], [4, 5, 6, 4], [6, 8, 9, 7]], 
                    index=['a', 'b', 'c'], columns=[0,1,2,3])
```

For instance set pairs values at (a, 3) and (c, 1) to 1
I know that I could do it with:

```
test.loc['a',3] = 1
test.loc['c',1] = 1
```

But I am looking for a oneliner

Comment: I don't think there is a one-liner for this general purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to generalize this, you can iterate of a list of tuples and set the values:

```
for r, c in [('a', 3), ('c', 1)]:
    test.loc[r, c] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The following might help if this is what you are looking for,

```
test.loc[['a','c'],[3,1]] = 1
```